# Ping vs. "connect" to remote server

Tags: http, tcp, server

Under what circumstances could you fail to ping a remote server with the `ping` command, but still be able to connect to it via other means (as long as it was still TCP/IP)?

Comment: Not sure this is a code-related question...? But a server which didn't implement the ping protocol, or a firewall which blocked it are the bovious answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ping command is usually using the ICMP echo protocol. It is not uncommon that this protocol is blocked by the peer. But if the peer is running some web server or similar you will still be able to connect to it, because it is not blocked.